# error when creating fibonacci generator sequence using setjmp() and longjmp()

Tags: c, coroutine, setjmp

I was trying to make something like `fibonacci` generator sequence (that is implemented using yield keyword in `python`) in `c` language using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` :

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jmp_buf mainTask, childTask;
void child(void);
int main(void) {
    long i = 1;
    if (!setjmp(mainTask)) {
        printf("%ldth Parent\n", i++);
        child();
    }
    for (int j = 0;j < 9;j++) {
        printf("%ldth Parent\n", i++);
        if (!setjmp(mainTask)) {
            longjmp(childTask, 1);
        }
    }
}
void child (void) {
    int c = 0;
    long i = 1;
    long j = 1;
    long k = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("i is:%ld   j is:%ld\n", i, j);
        k = i + j;
        if(i <= j)
            i = k;
        else
            j = k;
        c++;
        printf("%dth fib number:%ld\n", c, k);
        if (!setjmp(childTask)) longjmp(mainTask, 1);
    }
}
```

it only works correct for the first number.

*update:
I expected 2,3,5,8,13,...
but it produces 2, and nexts are incorrect (15digits incorrect numbers)

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the actual as well as the expected output?

Comment: And I really hope you're doing this just for experimentation. Because no sane programmer would create spaghetti-code like this on purpose for production code.

Comment: u are thinking correctly.I want to challenge myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your program has undefined behavior.

Quoting ISO 9899:1999, **7.13.2.1 The `longjmp` function**, paragraph 2:

> The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of
>   the `setjmp` macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding
>   `jmp_buf` argument. If there has been no such invocation, or **if the function containing
>   the invocation of the `setjmp` macro has terminated execution<sup>208)</sup> in the interim**, or if the
>   invocation of the `setjmp` macro was within the scope of an identifier with variably
>   modified type and execution has left that scope in the interim, **the behavior is undefined**.
>
> [...]
>
> 208) For example, by executing a `return` statement or **because another `longjmp` call has caused a
>   transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Your

```
        longjmp(childTask, 1);
```

statement in `main` attempts to transfer control to the `setjmp` invocation in `child`, but the call to `child` has already returned (through `longjmp(mainTask, 1)`).

This isn't easily fixable. C doesn't allow you to have two active functions running at the same time. Once you return from a function (by using `return` or `longjmp`), you can't re-enter that call.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this `error` you have to use `static variable` or `global variable`. A `static` variable remains in memory while the program is running. A normal or auto variable is destroyed when a function call where the variable was declared is over :

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jmp_buf mainTask, childTask;
void child(void);
int main(void) {
    long i = 1;
    if (!setjmp(mainTask)) {
        printf("%ldth Parent\n", i++);
        child();
    }
    for (int j = 0;j < 9;j++) {
        printf("%ldth Parent\n", i++);
        if (!setjmp(mainTask)) {
            longjmp(childTask, 1);
        }
    }
}
void child (void) {
    static int c = 0;
    static long i = 1;
    static long j = 1;

    long k = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("i is:%ld   j is:%ld\n", i, j);
        k = i + j;
        if(i <= j){
            i = k;
        }
        else{
            j = k;
        }
        c++;
        printf("%dth fib number:%ld\n", c, k);
        if (!setjmp(childTask)) longjmp(mainTask, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but I think for a way that don't need global variables

Comment: Your code still has undefined behavior. See my answer.